# Hide wrong values of a graph

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am building graphics using Matplotlib and I sometimes have wrong values in my Csv files, it creates spikes in my graph that I would like to suppress, also sometimes I have lots of zeros ( when the sensor is disconnected ) but I would prefer the graph showing blank spaces than wrong zeros that could be interpreted as real values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that works:
I used the Xlim to set my max and min x values and then i set all the values that i didnt want to nan !

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for I'm not familiar with matplotlib but I'm presuming that you're reading the csv file directly into matplotlib. If so is there an option to read the csv file into your app as a list of ints or as a string and then do the data validation before passing that string to the library?

Apologies if my idea is not applicable.

Comment: actually i have such function that I made and that put csv data into arrays, but I only have few possibility ( that i know of ) i can put erroned data to NaN but in this case MatPlotLib will zoom in like say if i want a graph for the span of a month but i have actual values for two days, it will show a graph for two days wich is not what i want i want the whole month whith empty spaces when wrong values, my other option is to put zeros, then it will show everything but the zeros are wrong values and this is ugly af

Comment: If the issue is spikes and troughs then perhaps for the spikes you could evaluate the gradient at that point in the graph or the average gradient of the graph and if the gradient to the next point is over a certain threshold then just remove the value and let MatPlotLib interpolate to the next data point. Similarly for zeros you could read ahead to see if it's a string of zeros and discount those values.      Obviously these approaches rely upon knowing what sort of graph shape you should expect to see at the end